# Google-apps-script debug: The resource you requested could not be located. (line 175, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, var

This is my first post here and I am really a newbie when it comes to programming so please be kind if I am making a fool of myself.
I have a script which updates my google contacts on submitting a new google form which has been running well for the last 3 years and stopped working a few months ago. I haven't changed anything in the script nor the form so not sure why it stopped working nor how I can fix it. Can you help?

I receive this error notification: The resource you requested could not be located. (line 175, file "Code")

This is what I have on line 175:

```
if (YourAddress && YourAddress!='' && YourAddress!=' ') newContact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS, YourAddress);
```

I have checked the Var definition in line52-53 and it seems correct:

```
case "Your Address":
YourAddress = itemResponse.getResponse();
```

Anything you can suggest to fix my issue?
THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: It would help if you could share a copy of your form and the script or perhaps share the code here instead. Of course, please remove any personal details, as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You error is due to a bug, which has already been filed twice on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

See [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/136194627) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/136104507). I suggest you to give the issues a "star" to increase visibility and hope that they will be fixed soon. In the mean time, you can try one of the workarounds other people with the same problem suggest, e.g.:

```
if (YourAddress && YourAddress!='' && YourAddress!=' ') {
  ContactsApp.getContactById(newContact.getId()).addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS, YourAddress);
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue now with the following line... 
I tried editing the line 176 like ou did for line 175 :

`if (PhoneNumber && PhoneNumber!='' && PhoneNumber!=' ') {   ContactsApp.getContactById(newContact.getId()).addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_PHONE, PhoneNumber); }`
`if (Nationality && Nationality!='' && Nationality!=' ') {   ContactsApp.getContactById(newContact.getId()).addCustomField(ContactsApp.ExtendedField.LANGUAGE, Nationality); } `
But it seems incorrect…
Any suggestion ?

Comment: You need to replace `addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_PHONE, PhoneNumber);` by `addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_PHONE, PhoneNumber)`